# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in functions.php on line 90

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook, formidable

```
<?php

global $oswcPostTypes;



//this is the folder that houses the function files to include

define('functions', TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions');



function fixObject (&$object)

{

if (!is_object ($object) && gettype ($object) == 'object')

return ($object = unserialize (serialize ($object)));

return $object;

}



$lang = TEMPLATEPATH . '/lang';

load_theme_textdomain('made', $lang);



//Get the post type functions

require_once(functions . '/oswc-post-types.php');



//Get the theme options

require_once(functions . '/theme-options.php');



//Get the review options

require_once(functions . '/review-options.php');



//Get the widgets

require_once(functions . '/widgets.php');



//Get the custom functions

require_once(functions . '/custom.php');



//Get the shortcodes

require_once(functions . '/shortcodes.php');



//Get the post type functions

require_once(functions . '/post-types.php');



//Get the post & page meta boxes

require_once(functions . '/meta-boxes.php');



//notifies users of updates

require('update-notifier.php');

//gallery

function my_gallery_to_slideshow_has_gallery( $params ){

return true;
**//this is the line 90 :(**
}

add_filter( 'mv_gallery_to_slideshow_has_gallery',    'my_gallery_to_slideshow_has_gallery' );



// average rating shortcode

function get_ppic(){

echo do_action( 'wordpress_social_login' );

}

add_shortcode('via-twitter','get_ppic');



function limit_posts_per_archive_page() {

if ( is_category() )

    set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', 9); // or use variable key:     posts_per_page

}



add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_archive_page');



function the_slug() 

{

$abc = $_GET['post_id'];    

$post_data = get_post($abc, ARRAY_A);   

$slug = $post_data['post_name'];    

return $slug; 

}



function category_has_parent($catid){

$category = get_category($catid);

if ($category->category_parent > 0){

    return true;

}

return false;

}

/*Created by Albert*/
```

/*end*/

```
add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'copy_into_my_table', 20, 2);

function copy_into_my_table($entry_id, $form_id){

if($form_id == 6){ //change 4 to the form id of the form to copy

global $wpdb;

$values = array('c_id' => NULL, 'review_title' => $_POST['item_meta'][86], 'post_title'    => $_POST['item_meta'][129], 'post_id' => $_POST['item_meta'][94]);

//replace 25 and 26 with the field ids of the Formidable form. Change col_name to the   column names in your table

$wpdb->insert('wp_magic_competition', $values);

 }

}

<!-- added -->
add_filter('frm_get_default_value', 'my_custom_default_value', 10, 2);
function my_custom_default_value($new_value, $field){
if($field->id == 25){ //change 25 to the ID of the field
$new_value = 'custom default'; //set your custom value here
}
return $new_value;
}
<!-- added -->

?>
```

Can't find what was the cause of the error..Im having an error after adding the code     inside  anyone can help me..thanks..formidable pro hooks , wordpress...
many thanks in advance :) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/wpperhou/public_html/dev/aor/thesports/wp-content/themes/made/functions.php on line 90

Comment: I'm guessing the code you've shown us is not from `functions.php`, which is where the error is occurring. You should be showing us what's around line 90 in `functions.php`.

Comment: can you show which is line 90?

Comment: after return true; inside function my_gallery_to_slideshow_has_gallery( $params )

Comment: Can you try re-uploading the file? Because if the first code block is the complete content of your functions.php file, then it should not cause a fatal error with unexpected $end. That usually happens when you haven't closed a code block(be it `if` `while` `for` `foreach`...), which can occur if your upload fails in the middle for some reason(I would most-often see those errors while the file is being uploaded, but I guess that's not the problem now).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this:

```
function limit_posts_per_archive_page() {

if ( is_category() )

    set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', 9); // or use variable key:     posts_per_page

}



add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_archive_page');
```

I can't see a closing `}` for the function.

I'm going to guess that this should fix it:

```
function limit_posts_per_archive_page() {

if ( is_category() )

    set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', 9); // or use variable key:     posts_per_page

}

}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_archive_page');
```

EDIT : Ignore this it's totally wrong.. I'm not one for if's without braces damnit!! (I'll leave it here for the lolz)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to

- Add a closing PHP tag (?>) at the end of your file
- Reupload your file to the server. Sometimes I get the same error as you and it does the trick. This could be caused by a ftp error.

Maxime